# Tizen.NET NfcCardEmulation throws UnsupportedException (with added privileges)

Tags: c#, .net, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

I had a issue with a Tizen.NET Api v4. Generally i need cardemulation in the watch, but while executing static method

> NfcManager.GetCardEmulationAdapter()

i am gettings logs

> [image: Devices Manager]

tizen-manifest.xml looks like (and he was generating by vs2019 with Tizen ext)
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="tizenapp" version="1.0.1" api-version="4" xmlns="http://tizen.org/ns/packages">
    <profile name="wearable" />
    <ui-application appid="tizenapp" exec="tizenapp.dll" multiple="false" nodisplay="false" taskmanage="true" type="dotnet" launch_mode="single">
        <label>tizenapp</label>
        <icon>tizenapp.png</icon>
        <metadata key="http://tizen.org/metadata/prefer_dotnet_aot" value="true" />
        <splash-screens />
    </ui-application>
    <shortcut-list />
    <privileges>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/secureelement</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/nfc</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/nfc.cardemulation</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/feature/network.nfc.card_emulation</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/feature/network.nfc</privilege>
    </privileges>
    <dependencies />
    <provides-appdefined-privileges />
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.nfc">true</feature>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.nfc.card_emulation">true</feature>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.secure_element">true</feature>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.secure_element.ese">true</feature>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.secure_element.uicc">true</feature>
</manifest>`

I dont know what i need to fix this problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple typo in the implementation. It's fixed in API5 and later.

https://github.com/Samsung/TizenFX/pull/578/files

I'm not sure if there's any workaround for this when targetting for API4, because it's not about a privilege but a feature.

Comment: I will try, it makes sens

Comment: I changed this lines in cloned TizenFX api and i was getting instances of **NfcManagerImpl**. I did getting any logs, but results are the same. When i using NfcManagerImpl properties process crashed with any logs and exception. I remember told you, i am cannot get access to any fields with except IsSupported and Is...**.**

Comment: You cannot edit TizenFX at your own because generally it's only available as a system package. Even if you build DLLs from source and install onto your device, they won't work by default.

Comment: But i did. I had Manager class with access to internal NfcManagerImpl. But result was the same, but with any logs.

Comment: How did you? Which DLLs do you have in your TPK? Also TizenFX is just a managed wrapper for native APIs, so if you understand how it works under the hood (Interop), you may further look into their native implementation.

Comment: I was changing .NET implementation, because he had a typo, a Impl is internal.

Comment: "Which DLLs do you have in your TPK?"
You didn't answer this. You can't have your own version of TizenFX on your device.

Comment: Bro, api v4 had a typo. Typo was fixed in version 5, but it wasnt compatible os on gear. Then i cloned the open-source repo and change bad strings. What do you not understand?

Comment: You don't even try to understand my comments. I'm done. Good luck.